# Finding the solutions of a nonlinear system of two variables

Tags: equation-solving

I need to solve the following system for the unknowns `x` and `y`.

```
x + b y - 3 c x^2 y - y^3 == 0
(-x/b) - y + x^3 + 3 c x y^2 == 0
```

where `b` and `c` are real parameters.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Eq1 = x + b*y - 3*c*x^2 y - y^3 == 0

Eq2 = (-x/b) - y + x^3 + 3 *c *x*y^2 == 0

Solve[{Eq1, Eq2}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: But it is not a good method to solve this kind of systems

Comment: You can get a more compact form by using the option `Cubics -> False` (solutions are then expressed as `Root` objects rather than radicals) and `Simplify`. `Solve[{Eq1, Eq2}, {x, y}, Cubics -> False] // Simplify`

Comment: What is not good about it?

Comment: Thank you dear sir